# How to change font textview in listview?

Tags: android, listview, fonts, textview, typeface

I am trying to change font via typeface. Please see [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/).

I want to change the 'currency' (text view) font in my .ttf font file. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

create a typeface and then to your edittext apply it as shown:-

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font.ttf");   
editText.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: @user1437739, You will have to supply the ttf font to your assets folder as well, or the `getAssets` call will return an exception

Comment: Thanks 4 repply, but I got forceclose if i use typeface.. :(

Comment: you need to place your font in assets folder so name your font as "font.ttf" and then place it in assets folder.
Else if u dont have your own font then u can use fonts that android provides just use editText.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html
have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:typeface="sans"
/>
```